# Am I using AutoLayout correctly? (Screenshots inside)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, autolayout

So basically I'm designing a layout for my app and I have difficulties adjusting my layout for iPhone 4. For an example look at these screenshots:

[image]

[image]

As you can see it barely fits on the iPhone 4 and the iPhone 6 has a blank space on the bottom. Am I using Auto Layout incorrect or is this the intended behaviour?

I also struggled not being able to make text fields smaller to fit the iPhone 4 screen in another layout.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: this isn't about using auto layout correctly, it's about UX and design - on the iPhone 4 your content should be scrollable so it's all accessible...

Comment: you are add uiscroller view that your bottom contain to scrolling and display your bottom containt.

Comment: well it depends on the number of constants and there type one thing i suggest is use both constant for example lets say you want to adjust height so set a constant of height  "greater than" for iPhone4 and "less than" for iPhone6.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you embed all views in a **UIScrollView** (with autolayout set), your content will be always visible(scrollable)
2. if you use **size classes**, you can set a specific UX for iPhone4